# update database from android issue

Tags: php, android, mysql

I did this tutorial. [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

It has many problem that finaly solved. but still create new item won't work. I checked the .php file by passing arguments to url and it's works correctly. but from android app

```
jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
```

result is not successful and `success=0` is my result.

This is my activity :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity{

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.19.101:81/android/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            Log.i("WEB", "c1");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
            Log.i("WEB", "c2");
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                Log.i("WEB", "c success="+success);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is php file:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['description'])) {

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $price = $_GET['price'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is logcat:

```
01-28 12:41:18.046: D/ProgressBar(28763): setProgress = 0
01-28 12:41:18.046: D/ProgressBar(28763): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
01-28 12:41:18.046: D/ProgressBar(28763): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
01-28 12:41:18.136: I/WEB(28763): c1
01-28 12:41:18.156: D/ProgressBar(28763): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-28 12:41:18.156: D/ProgressBar(28763): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
01-28 12:41:18.156: D/ProgressBar(28763): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
01-28 12:41:18.156: D/ProgressBar(28763): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
01-28 12:41:18.236: D/dalvikvm(28763): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 367K, 39% free 12037K/19624K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
01-28 12:41:18.266: I/WEB(28763): c2
01-28 12:41:18.266: D/Create Response(28763): {"message":"Required field(s) is missing","success":0}
01-28 12:41:18.266: I/WEB(28763): c success=0
01-28 12:41:18.286: E/ViewRootImpl(28763): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in all occurence of your php code.

Since you have used `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);`

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['description'])) {
```

Comment: it works know. but why post? can you explain me difference usage of get and post? thanks

Comment: Ok thanks I'll check. after this change my apps works but i can not pass the parameters from url. is that right?

Comment: You can also pass the parameter from url, If you plan to pass parameter in url, then you need to use $_GET method for that parameter,  say `ex.com?id=1333`, $_GET['id']